# Tizen Wearable Web Widget visibilityChange and Debug

Tags: debugging, widget, watch, tizen, visibilitychange

I am having some problems with Tizen wearable Web Widgets.

I just created a sample project with HTML + JS and tried to update page on events described in life-cycle -> On load / visibility change

the sample code can be found at: https://github.com/Ryccoo/widget-test/blob/master/widget/StockQuote/js/main.js

When I add widget I can see the text "something" -> meaning that onload function was successfully called.

However swiping to another widget and back does not trigger the visibilityChange event as described.

How do I correctly upload the contents when user scrolls to this widget ?

Another question is just how to debug the web widgets? You cant run debug to interactively debug the program with widgets (only for web apps) and when I want to print something to console I only see

> The web console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled.
>   To activate it, you should launch project with Debug mode.

How do I launch the widget in Debug mode ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Widget Debug feature is not Supported yet on Tizen Studio.

But I've test the code for Visibility Change event, and It worked fine on my Samsung Gear S3. Visibility Change callback is being called every time I change between widgets. You may give this code sample a try:

Project folder > Widget folder> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-container Panel">
        <div id="Visibility"> Visibilty: Init </div>
    </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Project folder > Widget folder> js > main.js

```
window.onload = function() {

};

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', visibilitychange);

function visibilitychange() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
        document.getElementById("Visibility").textContent = "Hidden";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Visibility").textContent = "Visible";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I somehow at least see console.log outputs in widgets? I will try the your code as soon as I can and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, **No you can't.** IDE shows the message: "Web widget project does not support for a debug mode" (Debug As > Debug Configurations  > Widget Project Name)