# JavaScript not working in Tizen Web Widget

Tags: javascript, widget, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm working on a [Tizen Web Widget Application](https://github.com/Samsung/tizen-docs/blob/master/docs/application/web/guides/applications/web-widget.md). My javaScript file resides in `MyProject >> widget >> MyProject >> js >> main.js`. Even if I change the text of an element in the `window.onload()` method, it doesn't work.

I've also tried the *accepted answer* of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411910/tizen-wearable-web-widget-visibilitychange-and-debug?rq=1) question but this also didn't work for me. Someone please guide me if there's any other check which I'm missing.

Comment: Could you let us know below things? How to make a project? Which emulator version is used for launching your apps?

Comment: I'm using [this](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/creating-your-first-app/web-widget.html) method for project creation and launching it on the `Emulator 4.0`

Answer (score 0):

When writing a Web Widget, the most problems are caused by fact, that it has limited number of features supported. The example is [not supported innerText and innerHTML](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/application-management/applications/widget-application#user-content-is-innerhtml-or-innertext-supported), which you could used to change the content of html from javascript 'by default'.

To change the content of HTML element you need to use *textContent* instead. I tried to reproduce your problem this way:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="container" onclick="changeContent()">
      <span id="content-text">Widget</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var changed = true;
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('[window.onload]');
  var box = document.getElementById("content-text");
  box.textContent = "starting content"
};

changeContent = function() {
    var box = document.getElementById("content-text");
    console.log('changeContent: ' + box.textContent)
    box.textContent = changed ? "abcdef" : "xyz";
    changed = !changed;
};
```

and code work well on Tizen emulator.

It is possible that you use feature, which is not supported. I suggest you checking carefully about features not supported in Web Widget and just not use them in your implementation.